# Where should I store my widget's preferences on the Configuration page on Android?

Tags: android, database, configuration, android-widget, sharedpreferences

^Question^

I think that it would be too complex to open a database. Does using shared preferences make my app's data size become big. Is there a temporary storage place for my data or should I delete the data in the shared preferences for that widget.

Short code samples are very appreciated :)

Thank you

Comment: If shared preferences is making your app's size to large, then you either have a misconception about its size or are storing way too much this way. SharedPreferences are the way to go for something like widget configuration IMO. Other solutions are a DB or file on SD/local storage. Give me some more info and I'll post a real solution.

Comment: @chris My app has a lot of widgets and it also needs to store a few important things. I'm just afraid that if I make too many widgets on the home screen, the app size may be too high (can I delete a preference when I'm done with that widget configuration?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it doesn't really take a lot of space :) I tested with 14 widgets on the home screen with different combinations of my big data. Only about 4KB after testing for a month while adding and replacing widgets. Should be no problem!

If smith posts his comment as an answer, i will mark him as correct